# How to choose the minimum value in one array that does not appear in the other using one line?

Tags: python, list

```
nearest_distance_table = [1,4,5,9,10,14,15]
nodes_explored = [2,10,14]
```

I want to assign a variable `next` to the minimum value of `nearest_distance_table` that is NOT in `nodes_explored`.
Is there a one-liner using `min()` to do this? I know how to do this using a for loop, but is there a way to do it with one line with min()?

Using a for-loop:

```
minimum = float("inf")
for I in nearest_distance_table: 
    if I < minimum and I not in nodes_explored: 
        minimum = I
print(I)
```

Comment: Variables should not be named `next` or any other built-in function or class name.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip sj totally forgot about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use comprehension as follows

```
nearest_distance_table = [1,4,5,9,10,14,15]
nodes_explored = [2,10,14]
minimum = min(i for i in nearest_distance_table if i not in nodes_explored)
print(minimum)
```

output

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the lists to sets:

```
lowest = min(set(nearest_distance_table).difference(nodes_explored))
```

Note that this will not work if you want to preserve duplicate values. For example,

```
nearest_distance_table = [2, 2, 4]
nodes_explored = [2]
```

will give 4 as the answer as the two 2s will be collapsed into a single value and then removed. This is the same behaviour as in your example.